# Incorrect type of input in constructor

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Target {
String name;
int amount;
double weight;
    Target (String targetName, int targetAmount, double targetWeight) {
        name = targetName;
        amount = targetAmount;
        weight = targetWeight;
  }
}
```

A completely arbitrary constructor which is not part of something bigger.

Suppose I create an instance of this somewhere
If I input the wrong type of argument

```
Target object1 = new Target("Apple", 4.32, "who knows?")
```

How can I make the constructor check if the type of argument is correct and if it isn't, ask to declare `object1` again.

Is it acceptable to write while loops inside the constructor? (using `instanceof` checks as long as the type is incorrect and ask to reinput)

Another idea is to create a separate method which deals with the `instanceof` checks, but the arguments have different types, is there a way to return the declared type of the argument?

OR am I completely over-thinking this and there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: Java is strong-typed, so the compiler will warn you about this.

Comment: You are over-thinking - java will ensure your constructor arguments are of the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Target object1 = new Target("Apple", 4.32, "who knows?")` will give you a *compile time* error. The method calls are *resolved* during compile time but the actual calls are done during runtime.

So, once it encounters the above statement, the compiler checks if a constructor *which is capable of taking* these arguments is present, if **no**, then you get an error.

**How can I make the constructor check if the type of argument is correct and if it isn't, ask to declare object1 again.** -
You shouldn't do it. A constructor is invoked when `new is called` i.e when an object is being created, If the arguments don't match, then the constructor itself won't be called. Use a *static helper method* for this (if needed).

**Is it acceptable to write while loops inside the constructor? (using instanceof checks as long as the type is incorrect and ask to reinput)**

You should not have any *business logic* inside a constructor. That's all. `instanceof` checks *may be* acceptable depending on context (case-to-case basis)

**am I completely over-thinking this and there is an easier way to do this** - YES. Don't call a constructor with *invalid* arguments. Don't put *business* logic in it. Validation logic is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to, because Java compiler will already give you an error during compile-time. It is Strong typed, meaning that a variable will only have one type and ONE TYPE ONLY.

The code you gave will not compile

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you give wrong parameters to constructor, java compiler will return an error. Answering your second question it is acceptable to use while loop inside the constructor.